# Contract - purpose of returned internal operations?

Tags: michelson, operation, contract

I keep seeing contract internal operations being returned empty (stack - 'NIL operation;') in the example Tezos Michelson contracts.

What is the purpose of the internal operations? Also, are there any example Michelson contracts available that are returning internal operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further contract investigation, I found out that these operations are used for internal blockchain operations like transferring tez to an account or calling a contract with parameters.

These operations are created from Michelson stack elements and are a series of bytes which represent a forged operation.

There is a example on the official Tezos developer documentation called reservoir.tz - http://tezos.gitlab.io/master/whitedoc/michelson.html#examples.